# Integration by parts wrt. a Morse function on its basin of attraction

Tags: morse-theory, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a Morse function with uniform nondegenerate Hessian at critical points, i.e. for some $\delta>0$
$$
\forall x \in \{\nabla f=0\}\;\forall \xi\in\mathbb R^n: \quad  |\langle \xi, \nabla^2 H(x)\xi \rangle | \geq \delta |\xi|^2 .
$$
*Edit:* Liviu Nicolaescu pointed out a condition to ensure the sublevel sets of $\{f\leq c\}$ to be diffeomorphic to the sphere  for $c$ large enough. Therefore, we impose $f$ to have at least linear radial growth at infinity
$$
   \langle x , \nabla f(x) \rangle \geq A |x| - B > 0 ,\quad A,B>0 .
$$
Especially, the above two conditions ensure that $f$ has only finitely many critical points.

Let w.l.o.g. $0$ be a local minima of $f$ and let $\Phi_s(x)$ be the negative gradient flow wrt. $f$, i.e.
$$
   \dot \Phi_s(x) = -\nabla f(\Phi_s(x)) \quad\text{and}\quad  \Phi_0(x)= x .
$$
In addtion $\Omega$ denotes the basin of attraction for $0$ or in other words just the stable manifold of $0$, i.e.
$$ 
\Omega = \{ x : \Phi_s(x) \to 0 \text{ for } s\to \infty \}
$$
Does $f$ satisfy Neumann boundary condition on $\partial\Omega$ in the sense that the following integration by parts hold
$$
  \int_\Omega (-\Delta f)\; g \; dx = \int_\Omega \nabla f \cdot \nabla g \; dx \quad\text{for all $g$ such that} \quad \int_\Omega |\nabla f| \;  |\nabla g| \; dx < \infty\quad ?
$$

**Strategy so far:**

- If $f$ is Morse-Smale, then $\partial \Omega$ is the union of stable manifolds heteroclinic connected to $0$
- for the integration by parts only the (n-1)-dimensional stable manifolds of saddles of index 1 are relevant.
- hence $\mathit{H}^{n-1}$ almost all $x\in \partial \Omega$ lie on a stable manifold of a 1-saddle and there the proof follows by contradiction and the definition of $\Omega$. Hereby $H^{n-1}$ denotes the (n-1)-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Is it necessary for $f$ to be Morse-Smale?
Is there some soft argument?
What are relevant references?

Comment: In your situation, is $f$ already given, and you look for conditions on $g\in C^1(\Omega)$ (that is, on its decay at $\partial \Omega$) in order that the formula holds?    

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. If you want I could give some more background. The focus is not on the noncompatness of $\mathbb R^n$, but more on the detailed structure of $\partial \Omega$ especially in the neighborhood of critical points of index larger 1. Here I expect the boundary of $\Omega$ to be nonsmooth with corners. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What troubles me is the noncompactness of  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR^n$. The boundary $\partial \Omega$ could be noncompact in a rather unpleasant way, difficult to control.   For example, there might exists a sequence of critical points $p_\nu$ of index $1$ going to $\infty$ as $\nu\to \infty$  such that there exists a gradient flow trajectory from $p_\nu$ to $0$ for any $\nu$.  In this case  $\partial\Omega$ will have an $(n-1)$-dimensional stratum for each $p_\nu$ making it hard to predict.

On the other hand, in the compact case, i.e., gradient   flows on  compact manifolds there is a beautiful paper of [Harvey and Lawson](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~blaine/FiniteVolFlows.pdf) that describes  one instance when an integration by parts holds.

**Edit**   Another issue you might neet to confront on a noncompact manifold is that of the multiplicities of the top strata of $\partial \Omega$. If $p$ is a critical point of  index $1$ and there are *infinitely many*  gradient trajectories from $p$ to $0$ they you would be hard-pressed to give a mening of the multiplicity of the stratum of $\partial \Omega$ corresponding to $p$.

In the compact case this multiplicity is   defined  by assigning  in a certain canonical fashion a sign $\pm 1$   to each such connecting trajectory and then adding up all these signs.  Clearly, if there are infinitely many connecting trajectory  this procedure does not make sense.

This is a serious problem that appears in  symplectic Floer homology. As far as I know, this is dealt with by taking advantage of  the peculiarities of each concrete situation.

Comment: I thought this case is ruled out, by the assumption of growth at infinity, i.e. $f(x)\to \infty$ whenever $|x|\to \infty$. Does this not ensure that there is not such a sequence of critical points going to infinity?

Comment: well,no, think e.g. to $f(x):=\sqrt{x^2+1}/2+\sin x$.
 

Comment: Also the function $x^2(2-\cos x)$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But since I don't want to have trouble with noncompactness of $\mathbb R^n$ let's assume that $f$ has at least linear growth at infinity. I will adjust the question.

Comment: The  big problem is that you can still have infinitely many critical points. You need to impose a condition that prohibits this from happening. 

Comment: I thought at some uniform condition for the nondegeneracy of the Hessian. I include it in the question...

Comment: A condition of the type $\langle x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \geq  A|x|^2+B$ ought to  take care of the  noncompactness of the critical set.  However, you also need to to worry about trajectories  that connect $\infty$ to $0$.  Also, you need to make sure that the flow is defined for all times.

Comment: I forgot to mention that above, $A>0$, $B\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Trajectories connecting $\infty$ and $0$ are explicitly allowed and are part of the question. I'm aware that the boundary of Ω could be wild. But still it should be a union of immersed manifolds from dimension 1 to n-1 as I indicated in the strategy if $f$ is a Morse-Smale function

Comment: When there exist  **infinitely many connecting trajectories**  from one  critical point of index $1$ to $0$,  then there  is **no integration  by parts formula**, even though $\partial \Omega$ is a union of strata as you suggested!

Comment: Do you have an exampple of such a situation in finite dimensions? Maybe I have forgotten a particular assumption, which prohibits such a situation. Thank you for pointing out possible problems, since I'm not from the field and just recently learned some very basic Morse theory.

Comment: I cannot think of one such situation in the finite dimensional case. However, if you make the assumption $\langle x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \geq A|x|^2-B$, $A,B>0$,  then this  does not happen. Under  this assumption the whole situation reduces  to  that of a flow on the sphere $S^n$ because the sublevel sets $\lbrace f\leq c\rbrace$ are diffeo to balls for large $c$. Even in the compact case you need to make some assumptions, namely a finite volume  flow assumption  as in the paper  by Harvey and Lawson I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ok, just linear growth is not enough. But, I don't want to impose quadratic growth. Already linear growth in radial direction, i.e. $\langle x, \nabla f(x)\rangle \geq A |x| -B$, $A,B>0$, implies sublevel sets diffeomorphic to balls. I wonder if in this context a condition $\lim_{x\to\infty} |\nabla f(x)|^2 - \Delta f(x) \geq c > 0$ is known in the Morse community? I'm asking, because both conditions imply that the associated diffusion operator with potential $f$, i.e. $\Delta-\nabla f\cdot\nabla$ has $0$ as isolated eigenvalue. Sorry for getting a little bit off-topic..

Comment: You can replace that condition with something like $\langle x,\nabla f(x)\rangle \geq   h(|x|) $, where $h(t)\to \infty$  as $t\to\infty$.  I have never seen  the condition you mentioned. However, I have to warn you that $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$ are very ill behaved objects. You need to  take extra care working with them.

Comment: Hve a look at Chapter 4 of the 2nd Edition of my book *An Invitation to Morse Theory*. There I discuss  the compactification of (un)stable manifolds of Morse  functions.  There are lots of pictures and you can get an example of the multitude of problems you can encounter.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and your reference. This helped me to realize that I have to ask the right question (cp. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121173)